# Creating a custom type for MariaDB procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, mariadb

In the PL/SQL world I would create a custom type with `type field_name is table of number index by VARCHAR2;` and use the new type like this `v_source_count source_code_ar;`

The [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/create-procedure/) for MariaDB states `types` can be any MariaDB type. It doesn't say anything about custom types though. Is there a way to achieve the same resutls of the PL/SQL above that will work for MariaDB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's true that you cannot create custom types in MariaDB, however if you need to simulate that functionality you can create a temporary table in memory. Note that creating a temp table has to come after any DECLARE statements.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE my_tmp_table (
    <fieldName> <datatype>,
    ...
) ENGINE = MEMORY;
```

The `ENGINE = Memory` bit ensures the table is only created in memory so you don't have adverse side effects.

Answer (score 2):

There are no "custom" datatypes in MariaDB (or MySQL).